# Jquery Chosen Plugin 1.0.0 in IE 8 - Compatibility view issues with text boxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

We use jquery chosen plugin and in our layout view we had to set the compatibility mode because otherwise plugin was not being applied.  Now as a result in other views text boxes will not allow users to type and cursor dissappears.

If I remove the following tag from the layout view then users are able to work with textboxes as normal but then the chosen plugin does not apply.

Since all my views use the same layout file, tis it possible to apply the following tag in a view where the chosen plugin is only being used. If I place this tag in the web configuration then chosen plugin works but not the textboxes.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=9"/> 
</head>
```